# Plotting lines in ggplot2 with given slope and intercept with legend

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataframe containing columns for slope and intercept. I want to plot lines corresponding to each intercept and slope for a given range and assign them color using a 3rd column. As I don't know how to plot geom_abline without assigning a plot to ggplot first, I used other columns x and y to get a plot and adjust the axis scale to see the abline lines and hide x y plot. So far so good. However, when I try to use color for abline, I can see the lines in different colors but I don't see the legend labels. Here is my sample code:

```
slope <- c(rep(.28,5),rep(.26,5),rep(.27,5),rep(.28,5),rep(.24,5))
intercept <- c(rep(-2.5,5),rep(-1.7,5),rep(-1.63,5),rep(-1.5,5),rep(-1.58,5))
wf <- c(1,1,1,1,1,5,5,5,5,5,8,8,8,8,8,18,18,18,18,18,22,22,22,22,22)
x <- c(seq(1:5),seq(1:5),seq(1:5),seq(1:5),seq(1:5))
y <- c(seq(1:25))
df <- data.frame(cbind(slope,intercept,wf,x,y))

ggplot(data=df,
   aes(x,y))+
  geom_point()+
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-3,0))+
  geom_abline(data=df,aes(slope=slope,intercept=intercept,color=factor(wf)))
```

Here is the plot I get using the above code
[image]

I also tried to use
    scale_color_manual(labels=c("1","5","8","18","22"))
to manually add the labels but it does not work.

Please help me to add labels or better how to plot lines with given slope and intercept to ggplot without having to fool around with other data.

Comment: Can you add the plot you get to your question please, as the legend appears with the expected labels for me.  (ubuntu R.3.2.4, ggplot2 v2.0.0) [ps: `ggplot() +  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-3,0))+  geom_abline(data=df,aes(slope=slope,intercept=intercept,color=factor(wf)))` should work]

Comment: I also see a legend.  I am running on Mac OSX (Yosemite) with ggplot2 v2.0.0.

Comment: On OSX 10.11.3 with gglot2 2.1.0 I see colored lines in the plot area and in the legend (on right side of the graphic) and numbers appear beside the colored line samples in the legend. Seems as though this is either unclear or unable to be reproduced so probably needs to be closed.

Comment: I have added the plot. I am using RStudio on Windows.

Comment: R 3.2.2 RStudio 0.99.875 on Windows 7

Comment: What version of ggplot2 are you using @beeprogrammer

Comment: Updated to ggplot2 version 2.1.0 and this solves my problem. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: great stuff @beeprogrammer . Ive now voted to close this as as an error that can no longer be reproduced.